# How to emulate the newest Opera Mini on Windows 10?

Tags: android, ios, emulator

I'll need an iOS or Android emulator that isn't too heavy and can either open file:/// from the computer or work with virtual hosts.

The laptop has intel celeron n3060 1.60ghz 1.60ghz and 4gb ram, no idea about the video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Android Studio.

You can access the Android filesystem via Android Device Monitor. In Android Studio go to Tools >> Android >> Android Device Monitor.